# Typescript class with unknown properties and methods?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a Typescript class that has unknown property names with known values as well as methods.  I don't have any problem with the unknown property names but when I try to add a method I get an error: "Property 'update' of type '() => void' is not assignable to 'string' index type 'Quote'."

EDIT: adding data info
Data would look like (I know the symbol is redundant but it just has to be that way):

```
{
'TQQQ': {
        symbol: 'TQQQ',
        lastPrice: 50
        }
}
```

```
interface Quote {...}

class Watchlist {
    [key: string]: Quote
    update() {...}
}
```

Here's a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIoFcD2lkG8BQyyAzgJ4C2ARpgDYBcJYUoA5ocjXMWAArNIMQ6KtHwBffPgSdixZAHU4YBAAsawbnnZEA2gGsIpBt2YgWAXQYZsEbcnQAHACZKIACgCUWoj58JMIMS0EAB0NJgsbgBEkNxRHnYSYj6SNBBgyADuSqrqmgC8yCAQmQo5ahpgnkA)

Comment: What if you index into it with `update`? Then it'd be a function, not a `Quote`.

Comment: Maybe you need something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w8xzdw) if your keys will have some sort of pattern to them.

Comment: They won't have any pattern.  I need to have the data and methods all within the class.  I guess I could put the data into another property but it'll cause a lot of extra typing.  Seems there should be a way to add a method to this class.  The class works fine until I try to add the method.

Comment: Also I should mention if I use @ts-ignore everything works exactly as it should.  I just hate doing that.

Comment: You should definitely be using another property to hold all of this.

Comment: Are you designing this class, or are you just trying to give types to an existing JS class?  If the former, you really should just refactor to use a form TS can handle, like adding a `quotes` property of type `{[key: string]: Quote}`. If the latter, you could end up `declare`-ing something that kind of works, similar to [this](https://tsplay.dev/wRXyQm), but there are weird side-effects.  Does any of that work for you? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?  (Pls mention @jcalz to notify me if you reply)

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear to me why would you need a class with endless unknown properties. It will not be handy. Consider adding a property like "quotes" where you store an object with all the quotes as [key:string]: Quote

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIoFcD2lkG8BQyyAzgJ4C2ARpgDYBcJYUoA5ocjXMWAArNIMQ6KtHwBffPgSdixZAHU4YBAAsawbnnYBHLJGINcAbQDWEUg27MQLALoMM2CGOQBePGIDc7dAAcAJkoQABQAlFpEkZEImCDEtBAAdDSYLMEARPpg6aHsRBIuRJI0EGDIAO5Kquqa7iAQ5QpVahpgYUA)

Comment: The reason is when I receive this data from an outside source it is structured the way I describe in my original post.  The property names are stock symbols, which could be any of thousands.  I see I will likely have to contain them all into another property name or just use @ts-ignore (probably the latter).  Thank you.